# Open pdf file in Adobe reader created in code-behind

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, pdf, adobe-reader

How can I open a PDF document that I've created in code-behind in Adobe Reader?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to open a pdf with the application that has a file association with it, do the following:

```
Process.Start("C:\foo\bar\mybook.pdf")
```

If you want to open a specific application instead (like Adobe Reader when you don't have a file association) do the same thing by passing the pdf file path as a command line parameter. You'll need to get the path to AcroRd32.exe from the registry because people may have different versions installed, or installed it to a different location.

```
Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe", _
              "C:\foo\bar\mybook.pdf")
```

The first option is generally better, because your software will respect whatever pdf reader your end-users have selected on their computer, or they may not have it installed at all.

Comment: That was so easy ... I've googled around for an hour and didn't find this!  Many thanks.